# How to prove this inequality $ \|\sqrt\epsilon x+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}\|^2\geq \epsilon \|x\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{2\epsilon}. $

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces

How to prove this inequality

$$ \|\sqrt\epsilon x+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}\|^2\geq \epsilon \|x\|^2-\frac{\|a\|^2}{2\epsilon}. $$

I think of using the triangle inequality but it is not that easy.

Is there a way to prove this ?

Comment: Hint: the RHS factors as $(\sqrt\epsilon |x|-\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\epsilon}})(\sqrt\epsilon |x|+\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\epsilon}})$

Comment: Lmost Equivalent to $(a+b)^2 \ge a^2 - b^2$. Which is true iff $ab + b^2 \ge 0$ which is not true iff $|a| >|b|$ and a and b opposite signs. If so $e|x| > |a|/2$. This *isn't always true.  But assuming we can select small enough e we can force it true for small enough e.

Comment: The LHS equals $$\epsilon\|x\|^2+\frac{\|a\|^2}{4\epsilon}+\langle a,x\rangle $$ where $|\langle a,x\rangle|\leq \|a\|\cdot \|x\|$.

Comment: So the equality is equivalent to $$\frac{3\|a\|^2}{4\epsilon}+\langle a,x\rangle\geq 0$$ that is granted by $$3\|a\|\geq 4\epsilon \|x\|$$